# $F = \nabla f $ for some smooth $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-forms

I am currently taking an university analysis class, and the professor of my class proved the theorem below yesterday.

If $B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open ball, $F: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is smooth, and curl$F = 0$ in $B$, then $F = \nabla f $ for some smooth $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

He then said that the theorem is false for the annulus $B_{2} \setminus \overline{B_{1}}$ where both $B_{2} $ and $B_{1}$ are open balls and $B_{1} \subset B_{2}$; the example is the function $F(x,y) = (\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} , \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2})$. $F = \nabla \theta$ locally, but $\theta (x , y)$ has no global definition.

I just don't understand almost everything above. First of all, what is $\theta (x, y)$ function and so how is $F = \nabla \theta$ locally? Why doesn't it have any global definition?

Comment: The moral of the story is that if you restrict your function to a small ball $B(p,\epsilon)$ inside its domain than you can find a function $f$ defined in this small ball such that $F|_{B(p,\epsilon)} = \nabla f$.
But you have to be aware that it can happen that you cannot find an $f$ defined over all your domain (e.g. $B_2\setminus \overline{B}_1$) such that $F = \nabla f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\theta$ is the angle in polar coordinates: $x = r \cos(\theta)$, $y = r \sin(\theta)$.
This has no continuous global definition: if you rotate once around the origin, it changes by $2\pi$.

Comment: Because the angle function changes by $2\pi$ as we rotate once, could I think of the angle function not even as a "function" by its definition so that it does not have a global definition?